# how to add html id to rails form_tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 2.2.2 and I would like to add an id to the html form code generated by the form_tag.

```
<% form_tag session_path do -%>      
<% end -%>
```

Currently produces:

```
<form action="/session" method="post">
</form>
```

Would like it to produce:

```
<form id="login_form" action="/session" method="post">
</form>
```

The [api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#M001697) isn't really any help and I've tried adding various combinations of

```
:html => {:id => 'login_form'}
```

with no luck.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

For `<element>_tag` you specify HTML attributes directly, as follows:

```
<% form_tag session_path, :id => 'elm_id', :class => 'elm_class',
                          :style => 'elm_style' do -%>
   ...
<% end -%>
```

It is for `<element>_`**`remote`**`_tag` constructs that you need to move the HTML attributes inside a `:html` map:

```
<% form_tag form_remote_tag :url => session_path, :html => {
                            :id => 'elm_id', :class => 'elm_class',
                            :style => 'elm_style' } do -%>
   ...
<% end -%>
```

Answer (score 28):

This code

```
form_tag(:controller => "people", :action => "search", :method => "get", :class => "nifty_form")
```

give as result:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/people/search?method=get&class=nifty_form" method="post">
```

But, if you use this structure

```
form_tag({:controller => "people", :action => "search"}, :method => "get", :class => "nifty_form")
```

you will get as result

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/people/search" method="get" class="nifty_form">
```

and it's exactly what you want

Comment: You think? Also - code only answers are not the best - try to explain the answer a bit.

Comment: Thats no problem. And, yes i think :)
If you want add class or method or anything else to form tag, you just need pack you controller and action like this {:controller => "people", :action => "search"}, then all you parameters after this structure will be work, if they are relevant

Comment: This really helped me out. Thanks @Kirill Warp

Answer (score 3):

```
<% form_tag 'session_path', :id => 'asdf' do -%>      
<% end -%>
```

Generates

```
   <form action="session_path" id="asdf" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="ed5c62c836d9ba47bb6f74b60e70280924f49b06" /></div>
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to put HTML options in `{}` to actually add `id` to `form_tag`, like this:

`<%= form_tag(some_update_path(@some_record), { method: :put, id: "some-id" }) do
<% end %>`