# How to add id to form_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am trying to add an id `(:id => "ratings_form")` to my `form_tag` in `HAML`, but can't find out the right place

```
= form_tag movies_path, :method => :get do<br>
  Include:<br>
  - @movies.all_ratings.each do |rating|<br>
    = rating<br>
    = check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]"<br>
  = submit_tag 'Refresh'
```

Comment: Add `:html => {:id => "rating_form}` to form tag. [Already asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618948/how-to-add-html-id-to-rails-form-tag)

Comment: The problem is that one is HTML and this one is HAML and I have the problem with the exact place

Comment: `= form_tag movies_path, :method => :get do` this line is pure ruby, it doesn't matter is it erb, haml or slim. I'm using slim and this ` = form_tag("/books/upload_book", method: "post", html: { multipart: true }, remote: true) do |f|` work perfectly.

Comment: Actually, it's not=) it goes to data-attributes.

Comment: But this:`html => {:id => "ratings_form"}` is generating this: `html="{:id=&gt;&quot;ratings_form&quot;}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for `slim`:

```
= form_tag movies_path, :method => :get, id: "form_id" do
```

Again, I'm sure this isn't depends on the markup language.

Answer (score 0):

On rails 3.0.20 this syntax worked for me:

```
<% form_tag({:action => 'some_action'}, {:id => 'form_id'}) do %>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try like:

```
form_for(@post, url: post_path , html: { id: 'post_id' }) do |t|
```

Comment: undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Comment: Question was for form_tag, not form_for