# add css display:none to erb block/form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

How do I add display:none to this form?

```
<%= form_tag(posts_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form", class: "nav-search-wrapper") do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This duplicate question! Please refer[here]


  [1]: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/618948/how-to-add-html-id-to-rails-form-tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `style: 'display: none;'`:

```
<%= form_tag(posts_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form", class: "nav-search-wrapper", 
    style: "display:none;") do %>
...
<% end %>
```